# Facebook Refresh Access Token: Server returned HTTP response code: 400

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-access-token

I am trying to automatically refresh a users OAuth2.0 access_token by calling the new facebook endpoint detailed [here](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

I am building a Java (SEAM) web application, the facebook authenticate is done using the serverside flow

I keep getting a response code 400, can anybody see anything wrong with the code below as I am not sure where I am going wrong...

Thanks

```
public static String refreshFBAccessToken(String existingAccessToken)
        throws Exception{
    try {
        // Construct data
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("client_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(FacebookApp.appId, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("client_secret", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(FacebookApp.appSecret, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("grant_type", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("fb_exchange_token", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("fb_exchange_token", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(existingAccessToken, "UTF-8");

        // Send data
        URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
        InputStream is;
        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
            is = httpConn.getInputStream();
            System.err.println("Input Stream..."+is.toString());
        } else {
            is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
            System.err.println("Error Stream..."+is.toString());
        }

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.err.println("Response: "+line);
            builder.append(line);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What's the text of the error response you're getting? The two most likely reason for this to fail is that the (existing) token has already expired

Comment: im only getting "Server returned HTTP response code: 400", but yes the token has already expired, isnt it possible to get a new token without the user requesting one?

Comment: No, the user needs to come back to your app for you to get a new token, the token extension only applies when you have a short-lived token and want to exchange it for a long-lived token (which you'd then cache client-side, for example)

Comment: Hi Igy, appeciate the help. My problem is that I am updating a users token when they use our 'Login With Facebook' button, in an attempt to keep the tokens alive, but whats happening is the original 60 day tokens are being replaced with 1/2 hour tokens! The login with facebook button uses the signed_request method...shouldnt this return a long-lived token?? Cheers...David

Comment: I actually posted the above questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299467/requesting-long-lived-access-token-on-serverside-flow